# Limit number of records in Dynamics CRM 2013 online

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I want to limit the number of records that can be added for a specific entity (Custom entity ) in CRM 2013 online. I am trying to create a custom entity such that only 4 (for example) records can be added to it. Once the limit is exceeded it must no allow to open the form to add record.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a synchronous Plugin.

Inside the plugin you will check how many records there are already for your custom entity, if the count reached your limit you throw an `InvalidPluginExecutionException` to advise the user about the limit and stop the creation of the record.